# DmlException Question

Tags: apex, trigger, force.com, dml

This question is related to a previously answered question: [Trigger won't Fire](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24891/trigger-wont-fire)

It looks like my organization has an existing test class that isn't playing nicely with my new Trigger. Could someone please help me get rid of the error. I think it's because another trigger has the record open and I'm trying to do something else with it? Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Here is the error:

```
System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id a0r40000005MyUPAA0; 
first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, MDwinning: execution of AfterUpdate 
caused by: System.FinalException: Record is read-only
Trigger.MDwinning: line 4, column 1: [] MDMeetingcStatsTT.cls   /src/classes    line     13
```

The test class that was there for a different trigger is here:

```
@isTest
private class MDMeetingcStatsTT {
static testMethod void testTrigger() {
try {
     MD_Meeting__c o = new MD_Meeting__c();
   insert o;

    System.assertNotEquals(null, o);
 }
  catch(Exception e) {
   List<MD_Meeting__c> l = [SELECT Id from MD_Meeting__c LIMIT 1];
   update l;
   System.assertNotEquals(null, l);
  }
 }
}
```

And here is my trigger that (thanks to user @eyescream) includes all the required opportunity fields:

```
trigger MDwinning2 on MD_Meeting__c (after update) {
List <Opportunity> oppToInsert = new List <Opportunity> ();
    for (MD_Meeting__c m : Trigger.new) {
    if (m.SAL__c=True) {    
     Opportunity o = new Opportunity ();   
    o.OwnerId = m.Sales_Director__c;
    o.Name = m.Name;
    o.StageName = 'Generate Opportunity';
    o.Market_Developer__c = m.Market_Developer__c;
    o.AccountId = m.Account__c;
    o.Type = 'Sales - New Business';
    o.CloseDate = System.Today()+150;
    o.MeetingLookup__c = m.Id;
    oppToInsert.add(o);
    }//end if
}//end for o
//try {
//        insert oppToInsert; 
//    } catch (system.Dmlexception e) {
//       system.debug (e);
//    } 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On line 4: `if (m.SAL__c=True) {` use the `==` operator for the equality check.

The compiler will let you use the `=` operator incorrectly for some reason.

This is read as an attempt to assign `m.SAL__c` the value of `true` which throws the exception you are seeing.

Comment: Odd. I don't recall Apex Code allowing that previously. I wonder when that changed? Also, it is for that reason that I always recommend that one doesn't compare Boolean values with Boolean values. Simply stating if(m.sal__c) is the same thing.

Comment: @sfdcfox Blast from the past, but this syntax works for checkbox only. Same reason you could do `Boolean a, b; a = b = true;`. This behavior seems like it would *always* have been a part of `Apex`, no?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I've since learned how to wrangle this behavior. I should probably write a post about it...